# How to get all videos on Android device

Tags: android

How can I get a list of all videos and their path that can be found on an Android device where is my app installed?

EDIT:
I am trying to make a simple video player, so the idea would be to display all the videos that can be found on the device and to play it on list item click.
Only problem is that i don't know how to get that info about videos, so I would be very thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, don't really know where to start..

Comment: I can't really find anything on the internet that would help me,so I haven't tried yet anything. Now I done the rest of the app,but only missing the pick video to play part.

Comment: I found this in the **Related** column, over there -->  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2911124/1267661  There are more useful links too, as well as Preet Sangha's.  Good Luck!

Comment: thanks! I will check it later and ask if I stuck somewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list all media in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531226/how-to-list-all-media-in-android)

Comment: This was very helpful -> stackoverflow.com/q/2911124/1267661 
Thanks for the help,and sorry for duplicate posting.

Answer (score 5):

If someone is still looking for answer please Try this method. This method will return list of path of all media.

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllMedia() {
    HashSet<String> videoItemHashSet = new HashSet<>();
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA ,MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
    Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
            videoItemHashSet.add((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA))));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<String> downloadedList = new ArrayList<>(videoItemHashSet);
    return downloadedList;
}
```

Comment: not working for me if folder programmatically created stackoverflow.com/questions/48934159/… please check this

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID};
Cursor cursor = new CursorLoader(contexts, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, 
            null, // Return all rows
            null, null).loadInBackground();
```

after you have the cursor you can iterate it and get all videos using the video id.

Comment: not working for me if folder programmatically created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934159/mediastore-not-working-when-folder-programmatically-created  please check this

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```
private void getVideoList() {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> pathArrList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            pathArrList.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    Log.e("all path",pathArrList.toString());
}
```

Comment: taking too much time to iterate video. how to speed up? i want to get all video path from device