# How to get list of video files in a specific folder in android?

Tags: android, file, list, video, mediastore

How to get list of video files stored in a specific folder using mediastore? currently i'm using this code

```
package com.example.videolisttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Cursor videocursor;
    private int video_column_index;
    ListView videolist;
    int count;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init_phone_video_grid();
    }

    private void init_phone_video_grid() {
        System.gc();
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
        videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                proj, null, null, null);
        count = videocursor.getCount();
        videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneVideoList);
        videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
        videolist.setOnItemClickListener(videogridlistener);
    }

    private OnItemClickListener videogridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            System.gc();
            video_column_index = videocursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String filename = videocursor.getString(video_column_index); 
            /*   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewVideo.class);
                  intent.putExtra("videofilename", filename);
                  startActivity(intent);*/
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context vContext;

        public VideoAdapter(Context c) {
            vContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.gc();
            TextView tv = new TextView(vContext.getApplicationContext());
            String id = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                video_column_index = videocursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
                video_column_index = videocursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);
                videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id += " Size(KB):" + videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
                tv.setText(id);
            } else
                tv = (TextView) convertView;
            return tv;
        }
    }
}
```

But this method scans the whole sdcard. i want to scan a specific folder. i don't want to use the filefilter method. please share any method using mediastore.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use this code for get videos from specific folder as:

```
  String selection=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
            String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"%FolderName%"};
            videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    parameters, selection, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

Its works for me like a charm.

Comment: It's works perfectly. Bro, can you please explain these lines:- " like?"; , parameters  , " DESC" and  the "%" sign

Comment: String[] parameters = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID} and like is statement for sql where you can specify the location to media data.Desc is for recent first to show into list.

Comment: But we can't trust this, because it's a searching mechanism. If you have two directory with almost same name it will merge the results.

Comment: I have used the same above code and replaced the Folder Name . where  String[] parameters = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; But I am getting cursor size as 0

Comment: The Above code does not work if folder has been programmatically created. Using File mediaStorageDir = new File("/storage/emulated/0/MediaRecorderLocation");

Comment: @DeepakJangir your code is not working if I am getting count `0` if folder has been programmatically created.

Comment: @sagarHudge you should first check if your created folder is existed or note

Comment: how to set column value in arraylist?

Answer (score 3):

```
private List<String> path_vid;
public void searchVid(File dir) {
    String pattern = ".mp4";
            //Get the listfile of that flder
    final File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            final int x = i;
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pattern)) {
                    // Do what ever u want, add the path of the video to the list
                       path_vid.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function is recursive, and search vids setting it into a list, the vids are searched from an especified folder, if u want to search vids into the sdCard, use:

```
File sdCard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
//For example:
//File vidsFolder= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Videos");
searchVid(sdCard);
if(path_vid.size()>0){
   //Convert list into array
   String[] array = path_vid.toArray(new String[path_vid.size()]);
   //Create Adapter
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item, array);
   //Set adapter to videlist
   videolist.setAdapter(adapter);
}else{
   //No vids found
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question is how to do this with Mediastore??

Comment: This answer could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503840/how-to-get-all-videos-on-android-device

Answer (score 2):

**LOAD ALL VIDEOS ON YOUR DEVICE**

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION};
            String sortOrder = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
            Cursor cursor = getApplication().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, null, null, sortOrder);
```

**LOAD SPECIFIC FOLDER VIDEOS ONLY**

```
            String selection=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
            String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"%Videoder%"};
           Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,selection,selectionArgs, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the specific folder, use:

```
.getExternalFilesDir
```

Answer (score 0):

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)

public void getVideos() {

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%/" + "Download" + "/%"};

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, selectionArgs , null);

    //looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
            String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION));
            String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
            VideoModel videoModel = new VideoModel();
            videoModel.setVideoTitle(title);
            videoModel.setVideoUri(Uri.parse(data));
            videoModel.setVideoDuration(timeConversion(Long.parseLong(duration)));
            videoArrayList.add(videoModel);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    VideoAdapter adapter = new VideoAdapter(this, videoArrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new VideoAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int pos, View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoPlayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

It's works perfectly For me.

Full Code https://github.com/PSOjha/PlayVideoFromSDCardFolder

Comment: @DavidLee You can Check My Github Repository, I Make Small Demo Example Over there. [ https://github.com/PSOjha/PlayVideoFromSDCardFolder ]