# How to get all video files in specific folder in android phone external storage?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I create a method that upload and save the video in "/download" folder in external storage in the android phone, if i use `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` all video files will be included, i want to know how to get the exact path of the "/download" folder in the phone storage?

because if i use this

```
private static final Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

videoCursorTitle = getContentResolver().query(sourceUri, projection,
                null, null, orderByTITLE);
```

if i use that it gets all the video from the external storage, how to get video in a specific folder? folder name is "/download"

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007342/how-to-get-list-of-video-files-in-a-specific-folder-in-android) is a answer to get video files in a specific folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 String selection=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
            String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"%FolderName%"};
            videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    parameters, selection, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

Comment: what does "%" foldername do?

Comment: % check the specific folder name which u will pass

Comment: just use this it will give u as u want

Comment: what does "?" do in the selection?
i read ? is used to follow guidelines, but i dont get it, what does it really do?

Comment: Is this method give u as u want in that folder dude

Comment: i tried your codes but it also include other videos from other folder outside of "download" folder

Comment: just try without % once

Comment: bro i delete last % "%download" same result, btw my folder is in "mnt/sdcard/download" at KSfilemanager in my settings

Comment: omg it work hahahhahahah i forget to put the selection and selectionArgs in the query thats why its not apearring hahahahha tnx bro you help me

Comment: bro this is the info of the "?" in the selection

Use question mark parameter markers such as 'phone=?' instead of explicit values in the selection parameter, so that queries that differ only by those values will be recognized as the same for caching purposes.

what does it means?

Comment: i know % means "specific" in my starting i just read once so i just apply this here and i think it works fantastic

Comment: i cant find the one right sign, where is it located?

Comment: This code is not working for me getting count `0` if folder programmatically created

Comment: Do one thing 1.Refresh your audio items 2. May be that format of song your android is not tasking in this category. Other wise code is running at my side