# how to show .mov files from gallery? is any other way to get .mov files?

Tags: android, memory, gallery, display, .mov

actually, I need to show .mov files in my project with a thumb(media store). same like video fetch from a gallery I know android does not support .mov file. but I need to show using any other way?

Example : Mx player all type of video formate

Now am using sample code for getting .mov file .this code not working for me.

```
 File[] file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
                 try {
                     for (File aFile : file) {
                         if (!aFile.isDirectory()) {
                             if (aFile.getName().endsWith(".mov")) {
                                 Log.e("VIDEO_FILE=====", aFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                 Uri uri_mov = Uri.parse(aFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                 mediaList.add(new ExternalMediaFileBean(uri_mov, false));

                             }
                         } 
                     }
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
```

Comment: Is the video present in the memory card or Internal memory?

Comment: video present in Internal memory

Comment: Okay, you are not getting anything in that log?

Comment: nope am not getting anything from log and one more thing I have .mp4 files in the same folder. all mp4 file is displayed.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007342/how-to-get-list-of-video-files-in-a-specific-folder-in-android) might help you.

Comment: No.this idea also not working for me. could you please suggest some other idea