# Select Videos By Its Folder Name MediaStore

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mediastore

I am creating a video player app, and i done most of the parts but when i started implementing the folder part to show all videos present in a specific folder through `MediaStore` it gives me result like below i explained it.
`folderName` - `/storage/external_SD` 20 videos in it.But it has only 5 videos in it, and rest is in the subFolders of this `/storage/external_SD` i.e, `/storage/external_SD/DCIM/Camera` it has 15 videos that means all videos are sumed up and result shown in `/storage/external_SD` only is 20.
I want 5 videos from `/storage/external_SD` and rest from other like `/storage/external_SD/DCIM/Camera`.
Thanks in advance suggest me something.
code for selection :

```
String folder = "/storage/external_SD";
String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " like?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + folder + "%"};
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

Comment: You can check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42099067/5059725) it is working fine.